# ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE Win32 equivalent

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm using Windows Hooks on my Win32 Application, I found `ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE` in MFC Application that is uses for handle posted messages, but how can I use this method in Win32 without MFC classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use RegisterWindowMessage() to get a message ID.  That you then use in Post/SendMessage() calls.  The code that processes the message also calls RegisterWindowMessage, using the exact same string.  And gets the exact same message ID.  And checks for a match in the window procedure with an if() statement.

The ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE macro doesn't do much of anything, it just hides that if() statement.

Comment: I have something like it static UINT UWM_MOUSEDBCLICK = ::RegisterWindowMessage( UWM_MOUSELDBCLICK_MSG ); but where i should do if statement, maybe here  // Main message loop:
 while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
 {
  if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
  {
   TranslateMessage(&msg);
   DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
  if(msg.message==UWM_MOUSEMOVE){
   // do smoething
  }
 }

Comment: No, in the window procedure.  The one you wrote for the window whose handle you use in the Post/SendMessage call.

Comment: Ok, but now I have another problem, global mouse click(outside of client window) does not receive, I wrote 

       if(msg->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN ||
 msg->message ==  WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN )
 PostMessage(hWndServer, UWM_MOUSEMOVELEFTBUTTONDOWN, 0, 0);

But it is not working

Comment: @TaronPro There is no such concept as *"global mouse clicks"* in Windows. If you need to globally intercept mouse clicks you will have to filter that at a lower level, for example by installing a global mouse hook.

Comment: I Have installed mouse hook by SetWindowsHookEx function in separate DLL, I referenced this dll to my project, but its post message only when its happens on my window

Comment: Well, that's pretty normal.  How does your DLL know what window handle to use?  Always favor a pipe.  Or your hook isn't hooking because, say, you're trying to hook 64-bit processes with a 32-bit DLL.  This has nothing to do with this question, click the Ask Question button to properly document your problem.